# Wordpress Database Huge wp_usermeta Table

Tags: database, user-meta, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a wordpress site with over than 700,000 users. Each user adds more than 20 rows to the wp_usermeta table ! this is causing very slow queries and the website started to crash, login failure and things like that. 
The table size now is over 1.5GB and when i try to optimize / repair, it simply get an error or crash.

Any solutions please ?

Comment: What did you end up doing regarding this?